# Shortest possible encoding of Guid that guarantees uniqueness

Tags: .net, encoding

Currently we are base 64 encoding our Guids when we need a unique url.

The question is, can we go shorter than 22 characters whilst guaranteeing uniqueness?:

```
        var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
        var idString = Convert.ToBase64String(id)
            .Replace("=", "")
            .Replace("+", "-")
            .Replace("/", "_");
```

Currently this will produce a string like `TwfQfblSTEuF7rLabS2bjA`

Comment: Is base64 a requirement? If not, what characters are allowed? What are your requirements for uniqueness? How many different values are you expecting? Can't you just use incrementing id? Why do you need the shortest possible encoding?

Comment: 1/2: No base64 is not a requirement, it just has to be as short as possible and contain URL valid characters. 3: That is is globally unique 4: No. 5: Cause I want pretty urls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base64 encodes 6 bits per character.  A guid has 128 bits.  You'll thus need 128 / 6 = 21.33 characters.  Can't do fractional, 22 is the hard lower limit.  You can only get less characters by encoding more bits per char.  That makes the URL encoding grotty, I can't think of a decent reason why you'd want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Only ASCII characters (real ASCII, not anything with bytes >=128) are valid in URLs. Base64 is already quite close to the shortest URL representation for a string of bytes you can get. If you want to get really pedantic, you should be able to shave a character or two off by using *all* the URL valid characters instead of just 64 (there's 80-something in total).

I'd say just go with base64. It's close enough.

Comment: out of interest, how would I go about doing this, or as @Hans suggests, is it just not worth the effort?

Comment: @Ben: What you essentially need is a base converter. The GUID is a number, and it can be represented in any base just like any number can, including base-80-something. Base64 can be implemented very efficiently because each letter encodes exactly 6 bits of data, but in your case each letter would encode a fractional numbers of bits, so you'll need a universal base converter instead.